# How to show the existence of limit cycles in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, limit-cycles

If we consider the following system:
$$
\frac{ \mathrm{d} \vec{x}}{ \mathrm{d} t}=\vec{f}(\vec{x})\qquad \text{    with  } \vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$ 
and assume we know a fixed point $\vec{x^*}$, we can analyse the stability of the system around the fixed point by proceeding to a Taylor Expansion up to the first term to understand if the point is stable or not.

However, if we continue up to the 2nd order terms, we can determine the existence of limit cycles, (by Hopf, Melkinov...) at least in $2$-dimensional systems.

$\implies$What are the existing tools and methods to determine the existence of limit cycles in systems in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

You can refer me to papers or books. Most of the literature I encountered only worries about stability of fixed points up to the linear order (Robert May, Gardner etc).

Comment: Looking for Andronov-Hopf bifurcation still works well in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, To obtain an Andronov-Hopf bifurcation, do I need to have strictly two eigenvalues that are purely imaginary? All the other eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ need to satisfy $\\Re(\lambda_i)\neq 0$?

Comment: Yep, this is the right condition. In other cases it would be a higher-codimension bifurcation point which is more complex than codimension-one bifurcation. Of course there are other codimension-one bifurcations that lead to a birth of limit cycle: for example, homoclinic loop/heteroclinic cycle destruction, saddle-node on invariant curve. However, as far as I saw, it's quite rare that you can prove analytically that any of these bifurcations happen in a particular system.

Comment: Could you direct me to references/articles on higher-codimension bifurcations if you know some sources please? Very interesting!

Comment: You can always refer to [Kuznetsov](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dturaev/kuznetsov.pdf) for bifurcations of codimension-1 and codimension-2.

Comment: whoah, he was actually my teacher during my undergraduate studies! Thanks, will look more into it.

Comment: That's amazing, lucky you :) Of course there are other books with info on this topic, but this one is completely devoted to it.